# Trim String based on Offset and Count

Tags: java, string

Is there an easy way to trim a String based on his Offset and Count values, that is, a function that returns `OO` for a String `FOOBAR` with an `offset` of 1 and a `count` of 2?

Obvious, one could write a simple function for this task, but I wonder if their is not a predefined Java functionality for this?

//edit: To clearify: I do mean the `offset` and `count` values defined within the given `String`, not external `Integer` values.

Comment: Out of interest, how much research did you do into the `String` class before asking?

Comment: Well, I was aware of the substring function. The solution proposed by you is what I ment by writing a simple function for it - as I still have to get the offset and count out of the String. As I thought this must be a regular problem, I hoped their is something along the line of string.trimToActualValue().

Comment: Oh, you mean for a string OO *backed by* a character array with vales FOOBAR? Your question isn't really clear. If so, you want the String(String) constructor. Will edit my answer when I get home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, now you've made your question clearer, it sounds like this is the scenario you're talking about, and the solution using the `String(String)` constructor:

```
// offset = 0, count = 6, backing array = { 'F', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'A', 'R' }
String original = "FOOBAR";

// offset = 1, count = 2, backing array = { 'F', 'O', 'O', 'B', 'A', 'R' }
String substring = original.substring(2);

// offset = 0, count = 2, backing array = { 'O', 'O' }
String trimmed = new String(substring);
```

---

Yup, [`substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29):

```
String substring = text.substring(offset, offset + count);
```

`substring` takes two parameters - the "begin index" (inclusive) and the "end index" (exclusive) - hence the addition in the above code.